# C# Populate generated datagrid using Selenium WebDriver

Tags: c#, javascript, selenium, automation, webdriver

I have a page that seems to generate a spreadsheet-style grid table using JavaScript. I am trying to populate the cells, but I cant locate the elements using Selenium.

When I inspect the cell I wish to populate using Firebug I can see that it has some long dynamic Id that Selenium cannot detect. It is visible when I use Firebug, however, when I right-click + view source, there is no grid visible.

I have tried all selectors (id, css, xpath, etc) and have tried populating using IJavascriptExecutor. Nothing seems to work, and I am about ready to give up.

I have even tried running the IDE; it fails when it comes to the dynamic fields.

Any assistance would be much appreciated.

Comment: Any code of page or JS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a work around (its kind-of obvious and not ideal, but meh...)

Instead of targeting the grid programmatically, I just simulated keystrokes using an instance of Actions:

```
Actions actions = new Actions(driver);
actions.SendKeys(Keys.Tab).Build().Perform();
actions.SendKeys("text to enter").Build().Perform();
```